# Multiple SignalR connections in ABP

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I have a project that is using ASP.NET Zero template. I have successfully integrated SignalR into my solution and the real-time notification works fine. What I want is adding another hub to my solution or extending the existing SignalR hub to add more to it.

In the [SignalR AspNetCore Integration](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration) document, it says to add the following to the **Startup.cs** file:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
     routes.MapHub<AbpCommonHub>("/signalr"); // default hub
     routes.MapHub<HitchNotification.HitchHub>("/hitchHub"); // my hub
});
```

The issue, however, is the client where I need to set up the connection! In the **SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.ts**, it sets the URL to use the `'/signalr'` hub (default one).

```
export class SignalRAspNetCoreHelper {
    static initSignalR(): void {

        var encryptedAuthToken = new UtilsService().getCookieValue(AppConsts.authorization.encrptedAuthTokenName);

        abp.signalr = {
            autoConnect: true,
            connect: undefined,
            hubs: undefined,
            qs: AppConsts.authorization.encrptedAuthTokenName + "=" + encodeURIComponent(encryptedAuthToken),
            url: AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl + '/signalr'
        };

        jQuery.getScript(AppConsts.appBaseUrl + '/assets/abp/abp.signalr-client.js');
    }
}
```

If I change the `'/signalr'` to `'/hitchHub'`, it works fine. But I want both in my application! I tried to create a helper for my own hub similar to the **SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.ts** and initialize it in the **app.component.ts**:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.appSession.application && this.appSession.application.features['SignalR']) {
        if (this.appSession.application.features['SignalR.AspNetCore']) {
            SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.initSignalR();
            HitchHubHelper.initHitchHub();  
        } 
    }
}
```

But it seems that the `abp.signalr` can't have multiple connections to different hubs.

So, basically I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any way that I could add my own hub's functions to the default `AbpCommonHub`? That way, I could simply modify the **abp.signalr-client.js** file.
2. If the above is impossible, how can I have multiple hubs on the `abp.signalr` to be accessible anywhere within my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there any way that I could add my own hub's functions to the existing default AbpCommonHub? that way I could simply modify the abp.signalr-client file

Sure. Inherit `AbpCommonHub`:

```cs
public class HitchHub: AbpCommonHub
{
    // Ctor omitted for brevity

    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("getMessage", string.Format("User {0}: {1}", AbpSession.UserId, message));
    }
}
```

Replace hub:

```cs
// routes.MapHub<AbpCommonHub>("/signalr");
routes.MapHub<HitchHub>("/signalr");
```

> 2. If the above is impossible, how can I have multiple hubs on the abp.signalr to be accessible anywhere within my application?

The above is not impossible, but I'll answer this anyway to demonstrate multiple hubs (for Angular).

Inherit `AbpHubBase`:

```cs
public class HitchHub : AbpHubBase, ITransientDependency
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("getMessage", string.Format("User {0}: {1}", AbpSession.UserId, message));
    }
}
```

Map hub:

```cs
routes.MapHub<AbpCommonHub>("/signalr"); // No change
routes.MapHub<HitchHub>("/signalr-hitchHub"); // Prefix with '/signalr'
```

## Usage

This requires `Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR` `v3.5.0-preview3`.

Modify **SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.ts**:

```js
abp.signalr = {
    autoConnect: true,  // No change
    connect: undefined, // No change
    hubs: undefined,    // No change
    qs: AppConsts.authorization.encrptedAuthTokenName + "=" + ... // No change
    remoteServiceBaseUrl: AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl,         // Add this
    startConnection: undefined,                                   // Add this
    url: '/signalr' // Changed from: AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl + '/signalr'
};

// Modify the following block
jQuery.getScript(AppConsts.appBaseUrl + '/assets/abp/abp.signalr-client.js', () => {
    var hitchHub;

    abp.signalr.startConnection('/signalr-hitchHub', function (connection) {
        hitchHub = connection; // Save a reference to the hub

        connection.on('getMessage', function (message) { // Register for incoming messages
            console.log('received message: ' + message);
        });
    }).then(function (connection) {
        abp.log.debug('Connected to hitchHub server!');
        abp.event.trigger('hitchHub.connected');
    });

    abp.event.on('hitchHub.connected', function() { // Register for connect event
        hitchHub.invoke('sendMessage', "Hi everybody, I'm connected to the chat!"); // Send a message to the server
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I have ended up with the first option of inheriting from the AbpCommonHub. My SendMessage method works fine. But for some reason the real time notification has stopped working! I am not receiving any error! Any comment?

Comment: What else did you modify?

Comment: Well nothing! I was expecting the connection.on('getNotification', function (notification) {
            abp.event.trigger('abp.notifications.received', notification);
        }); works as before but it has stopped working since the change.

Comment: Oh, you need to replace `IRealTimeNotifier` because of [this](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/097dacf2e2217273cb88f46f11df3257807d9572/src/Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR/AspNetCore/SignalR/Notifications/SignalRRealTimeNotifier.cs#L31).

Comment: Aaron, as mentioned before, the real-time notification was working before the above change and even now if I revert the code back to it initial state that will start working. I have recently updated all the DLL and I believe my project already has the modified version of the IRealTemeNotifier.

Comment: You didn't click the link? `SignalRRealTimeNotifier` uses `AbpCommonHub`.

Comment: Ah! you right! so, the only option that I would have is having my own Hub besides to the signalr one? right?

Comment: That seems preferable.